# Python-Binance.US api: APIError: (code=-1013): Filter failure: LOT_SIZE

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I am receiving an API error when trying to place a sell order. My buy orders are working fine.

Request parameters:

```
{'symbol': 'BTCUSD', 'side': 'SELL', 'type': 'MARKET', 'quantity': '0.04965054', 'newOrderRespType': 'RESULT', 'timestamp': 1662864898133}
```

API error:

```
{'code': -1013, 'msg': 'Filter failure: LOT_SIZE'}
```

Comment: from the [binance docs](https://docs.binance.us/#matching-engine-errors): "Filter failure: LOT_SIZE" Quantity is too high, too low, and/or not following the step size rule for the symbol

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken It seems my quantity meets the filter rules: {"filterType":"LOT_SIZE","minQty":"0.00000100","maxQty":"9000.00000000","stepSize":"0.00000100"}

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was a result of the stepSize. Here is the code I used to fix it:

```
quantity = str(step_size * math.floor(float(quantity) / step_size))
```